# CRC: false positive under some circumstances

Tags: algorithms, computer-networks, crc

Consider two computers $A$ and $B$. $A$ uses $G$ and $B$ uses $G'$ for the CRC computation. It is given that $\deg G \ne \deg G'$. Computer $A$ wants to send a data $D$.

The claim says that:

> There couldn't be data $D$ such that $A$ sends it as a CRC-message corresponding to computer $B$ which will accept it as a valid message. Why is that?

We know that computer $A$ sends $D\cdot 2^r \text{ XOR } R$ ($r$ is the degree of $G$) and computer $B$ divides by $G'$. So in other words, why can't $G'$, accidentally, divide $D\cdot 2^r \text{ XOR }  R$?

Obviously it has something to do with the fact that $\deg G \neq \deg G'$ but I didn't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the CRC encoding mentions the degree of the polynomial?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, the only things sent is the encoded message.